# Is it possible to have pets on Furrowfield?

Tags: dragon-quest-builders-2

I really wanted to relocate my pets to the story islands, but it doesn't seem to let me.  Is this unlockable later on?  Is there something I have to do first before pets (and monsters) can be relocated (or even join your party and follow you) to the story islands?